Update references to immutable object
Please, imagine a very simple (and awkward) concept. I have created it to demonstrate a much complex problem.
Lets have immutable class Customer. Then we have a object order of class Order that references customer. Now, I want to change customer phone number and want this change to be reflected in all existing orders *.
Indeed, I can write an event handler that is fired by Customer property change and this handler checks all instances of the Order class and update where necessary. But what if I later write class Invoice, whose objects also reference Customer, but forget to update the handler?
I there some better pattern than observer (events)? If not, is there a way to detect, that I forgot to edit the event handler? Preferably by the compiler.
*) I know, its against the reason why the Customer is immutable, but bite the bullet here, please

This doesn't make sense. How exactly do you change a customer's phone number in the first place if Customer is immutable?

Sorry not being clear. By "changing" phone number I mean creating a new instance with different value, of course.

If Customer is truly immutable, and assuming we aren't planning on subverting the type model by nefarious means, there is no purpose using a notification event, because nothing can ever change that might require notification.
Your only real option here would be to introduce an extra layer - CustomerProxy or similar (which is mutable), such that your Order, Invoice etc don't have a direct reference to Customer, but only to the shared CustomerProxy; then "updating" the Customer really means swapping the Customer instance that CustomerProxy points to.
Alternatively: change the problem such that it isn't immutable.

Well, if the Customer is mutable, then the problem is trivial as the other objects are holding object references to customer, so the change of customer field "updates" immediately.

Ok, the proxy idea sounds good. As my problem is rather more complex it means creating something like 'Reference Manager' that would be responsible for controlling references throughout the whole app. Do you have idea about some already existing design pattern? Not to reinvent the wheel.
